# Multiprocessing strange behaviour?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am using multiprocessing from Python for testing purpose and there are somethings I don't understand.

A priori, processes have their own memory space so we can't share and Python class between them.

But look at my code:

```
import sys, 
import time
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process

class MainClass():
    def __init__(self, q):
        self.q = q 
        print("Queue in Main", q)

    def start_p(self):
        p = Proc(self.q)
        p.processing()

    def run_p(self):

        p = Process(target=self.start_p, args=())
        p.start()
        return p

class Proc():
    def __init__(self, q):
        self.q = q  

    def processing(self):
        print("Queue in process", self.q)

        n = ''
        try:
            n = self.q.get(0) # Get first item in the "queue"
        except KeyError as e:
            print("NOK", e)

        print("GET: ", n)
        print('Size: ',  self.q.qsize())


if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Creating a queue
    q = Queue()

    # Add 10 numbers in the queue
    for i in range(0,10):
        q.put(i)

    # Add the queue to Main Class
    s = MainClass(q)
    print("Initial queue size", q.qsize())

    # Starting 3 process
    p1 = s.run_p()
    p2 = s.run_p()
    p3 = s.run_p()


    #time.sleep(2)
    print("Final queue size", q.qsize())
```

I have created a queue on main process, with 10 numbers.
Then, I ran 3 process so each one run a task consting of just getting (and delete) first item in a queue.

What I misunderstand is how can this program work and return a final queue 7 ?
It seems the queue is shared...but the object itself (multiprocessing) is located in different memory place...
But there is no "pointer" mecanism in python ?

The result when I run the programm below:

[image: Result]

Behaviour is almost the same on linux except the memory adress is the same for all instances.

[image: l]

Please can someone explain me ?

Comment: Unless I misunderstood your question, the queue is shared because you shared it by creating `s = MainClass(q)`. All `s.run_p()` calls will work on the same queue which is `self.q` inside your classes and it corresponds to the `q = Queue()` from the beginning of your main program. It's all one object.

Comment: A multiprocessing queue is responsible for doing the IPC work to communicate with the other processes. It doesn't need to be the same object to have access to the same data.

Comment: ...that said, when it's created *before* copies of the original process are forked off (on platforms that work that way), those copies inherit the same instance and thus have it located in the same virtual memory space (of course, mapped to different physical memory for each process... at least, as soon as any change is made that would make the virtual memory pages not be identical to each other).

Comment: See the discussion of copy-on-write in virtual memory management at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your basic premise is not entirely correct. While multiple processes indeed have their own memory space, that does not mean they cannot exchange data.

In fact there are multiple mechanisms for programs to share data. These are generally called "inter process communication" or IPC. For example;

- shared memory
- pipes
- sockets

Under the covers, a `multiprocessing.Queue` uses a `multiprocessing.Pipe`.
This in turn is a Python wrapper for an *operating system* communication pipe. On ms-windows this is an operating system primitive called a named pipe. On many other operating systems pipes are based on file descriptors.

The point is that even when the Queue is inherited in the child processes, they are all connected to the *same* operating system object.
That is basically why they can communicate with each other.

(Note that this is of necessity a simplification; If you *really* want to know how it works, read the `multiprocessing` module Python code.)

Comment: and ... this answer could be improved by mentioning _pickleing_ - which is how the python objects are sent over the pipe (important because that tells you how an entire set of interconnected objects are sent ... and what the limitations are)

Comment: @davidbak I left out a lot of details *on purpose*. My goal was to focus on what enables a `multiprocssing.Queue` to communicate between different processes. While the fact that objects sent over a pipe are pickled is important and has consequences for what you can send, that doesn't really go to the heart of the question, in my opinion.

Comment: That's fine.  I thought there was more to the question but your answer is good.